# How to know if hydrangea alive?

Tags: leaves, hydrangea

Have found a hydrangea paniculata (lime white) in a local (Austria, zone7) hardware store/ garden center on discount today (november 2023). Was not sure whether to buy it, as it did not have any leaves left - my hydrangea macrophylla still has all its green leaves. Both plants are in a pot (20+ cm diameter).

Should i buy it? How to know if its alive and reasonably healthy, without breaking any branches? Besides pulling it out of the pot (if possible).

Comment: Why not? Nothing to lose. Get it into the ground now. A green hydrangea? Cool.

Comment: Snap a stem. If it breaks and sounds like a matchstick, everything above is dead. Keep going.

Comment: A pic would be useful.  If it did not have any green stuff it is likely dead.  If there is green stuff maybe it has a chance.  It does not sound "reasonably healthy" to me - but then again I've only ever lived in places where Hydrangeas are evergreens and I don't know that they can survive outdoors in Hardiness zone 7!